# Why do deleted files continually reappear?

Tags: files, filesystems, linux-mint, cron, nemo

I've been having a strange issue recently, where I would delete files from a location (i.e. Desktop), and then empty the Trash. However, a day or so later (I'm not sure exactly what triggers it), the files reappear with new permissions (644).

How do I either figure out what's causing it, or stop it completely? It's been going on for quite sometime now, and it's rather annoying considering I spent ~1 hour cleaning my home folder, and now it's back to the way it was.

P.S. I'm running Linux Mint 15 Olivia

The cron jobs, as requested:

```
# ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ luckybackup entries ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
@reboot    sleep 180;    /usr/bin/luckybackup -c --no-questions --skip-critical /root/.luckyBackup/profiles/Jason.profile > /root/.luckyBackup/logs/Jason-LastCronLog.log 2>&1
# ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ end of luckybackup entries ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

and

```
0 21 * * * fwbackups-run -l 'Daily Backup' # autogenerated by fwbackups
```

Comment: Which files have you been deleting? Certain configuration files (eg dot files in home directory) will just be recreated next time the application that uses them runs.

Comment: Nope, generic files such as movies, bash scripts, PDFs, etc.

Comment: Which file manager are you using?

Comment: Nemo, the default for Linux Mint.

Comment: Definitely sounds like a bug with that. Not sure how much help you will get with it here, most of the stuff is a lot more system internals/command line based. Linux Mint forums is probably better, but you never know who might come by here. As a workaround you could try emptying the Trash folder from the command line with `rm` (I think the folder is `~/.local/share/Trash`)

Comment: I empty it with `sudo rm -f -r *` (in the appropriate directory of course), but the files still come back somehow.

Comment: That's quite odd. You can verify that this is definitely a file manager related issue by removing the files directly with `rm`. Btw, using `sudo` is unnecessary if the files are owned by you (and potentially dangerous when using globs).

Comment: Can you post the output of running `for user in $(cut -f1 -d: /etc/passwd); do crontab -u $user -l; done` as root? This is used to list all cron jobs for all users.

Comment: The cron job info has been edited into the question.

Comment: Maybe you could run a script using `inotify` to let you know when the file reappears.

Comment: Have you been restarting your computer? Perhaps the lost+found picks it up, and is able to restore it, so does...

Comment: I restart it ever 2 days or so.

Answer (score 1):

It [looks like Linux Mint 15 Olivia uses the aufs and/or unionfs filesystems.](http://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?p=385566#p385566)

I've not used Linux Mint but [Puppy Linux](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PuppyLinux) uses [aufs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aufs) and the behavior you describe is indicative of a multi-layered filesystem like aufs.

The short answer is that when you delete files that are part of the original distribution, they are not actually deleted, but they do disappear from your file listings. If you save your filesystem changes during shutdown, they will be preserved for when you start up again. If you don't, your reboot/restart will come up with the original files. All changes are lost.

**The details...**
[Unionfs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unionfs) and [Aufs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aufs) improve reliability by structuring the filesystem in multiple layers. This is analogous to graphical overlays as are seen in Google Maps, and other GIS systems. The filesystem, as distributed, is the bottom layer and kept read-only so you can always rollback to it if necessary.

Subsequent additions/changes are stored in one or more upper layers. Deletions of lower layer files don't actually delete. Puppy (and perhaps Mint) creates a hidden "whiteout" file in the writable upper layer that hides the "deleted" file in the lower layer.

All this magic is only possible because bootup puts the filesystem layers, in whole or in part, in RAM instead of on disk. You can probably see the layers by looking in the directory used to initialize the ramdisk (`/initrd` on PuppyLinux).

***CAUTION***
If you were to delete files from within your equivalent to `/initrd` instead of from within the usual directories, you would probably mess up the layering and, as they say, "the results would be unpredictable".